# soundcloud api - how to check recorded track is active or not?

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

How can I check recorded track is uploaded and active for embed.

I want to show embed preview of track once it upload is done.

but I am getting 404 error from scPlayer api while resolving the url.

Is possible to track availability of track, based on that i can use sCplayer()

for resolving track.

Any help?

Thanks
Peter

Answer (score 0):

I know in the `/tracks` resource there is a attribute called `state` which could be what you're looking for.

On their docs, the example value they give is `finished`, so maybe it would read `uploading` or `processing` before the track is ready. NB: I haven't tried this myself.

```
{
  "id": 13158665,
  "created_at": "2011/04/06 15:37:43 +0000",
  "user_id": 3699101,
  "duration": 18109,
  "commentable": true,
  "state": "finished",
  "sharing": "public",
  "tag_list": "soundcloud:source=iphone-record",
  "permalink": "munching-at-tiannas-house",
  "description": null,
  "streamable": true,
  "downloadable": true,
  "genre": null,
  "release": null,
  "purchase_url": null,
  "label_id": null,
  "label_name": null,
  "isrc": null,
  "video_url": null,
  "track_type": "recording",
  "key_signature": null,
  "bpm": null,
  "title": "Munching at Tiannas house",
  "release_year": null,
  "release_month": null,
  "release_day": null,
  "original_format": "m4a",
  "original_content_size": 10211857,
  "license": "all-rights-reserved",
  "uri": "http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/13158665",
  "permalink_url": "http://soundcloud.com/user2835985/munching-at-tiannas-house",
  "artwork_url": null,
  "waveform_url": "http://w1.sndcdn.com/fxguEjG4ax6B_m.png",
  "user": {
    "id": 3699101,
    "permalink": "user2835985",
    "username": "user2835985",
    "uri": "http://api.soundcloud.com/users/3699101",
    "permalink_url": "http://soundcloud.com/user2835985",
    "avatar_url": "http://a1.sndcdn.com/images/default_avatar_large.png?142a848"
  },
  "stream_url": "http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/13158665/stream",
  "download_url": "http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/13158665/download",
  "playback_count": 0,
  "download_count": 0,
  "favoritings_count": 0,
  "comment_count": 0,
  "created_with": {
    "id": 124,
    "name": "SoundCloud iPhone",
    "uri": "http://api.soundcloud.com/apps/124",
    "permalink_url": "http://soundcloud.com/apps/iphone"
  },
  "attachments_uri": "http://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/13158665/attachments"
}
```

from: http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/tracks

alternatively, there could be another value, like `duration` or `stream_url` that will read NULL until the track is ready.